# How to set icon for resized buttom group in excel ribbon?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Hi I'm creating an excel addin that include a new ribbon tab, and I set the corresponding icon for each buton. But, anytime the excel window is resized and the button group shows an empty ball icon. How can I set an icon for the whole group to be displayed when resized?

In this image - [Grouped & Ungrouped example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s19Y.png) you can see one group ("Simulation") that is not grouped, and the other groups "Add New Products" & "Scenarios" that are grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Add in image to the group in the XML. For example:

> ```
>           <group id="groupName" label="groupLabel" image="imageName">
> ```